# Most efficient way to read IP address from file

Tags: c, linux, ip

I have text file with many(milions) of IP4 and IP6 addresses. I need to read all of them as fast as possible.

I know about `inet_pton` but I don't know if address is IP4 or IP6 so I would need to do "try and error" approach where I try IP4 and if it fails, try IP6. But I don't like this solution because I would be needlessly parsing IP4, when it is IP6.

Comment: Is it a text file? If the file doesn't include type information, then how else would you be able to do it? You can't magically know the type without looking at at least *some* of the data to see if it fits the criteria.

Comment: @unwind Text file. Best would be to have some intelligent function that efficiently tries parsing both and returns one that fits. C# does have one.

Comment: And C#'s function probably does the same "trial and error" approach internally.

Comment: My guess is that reading the textfile into memory will take longer than checking those values to be either ip4 or ip6.. So just make sure you dont access the textfile more than you need to

Comment: @interjay Have source for that?

Comment: @Euphoric you should provide sample text from your text file so that it is clear to help you.

Comment: @Atique It is simply file where each line is either IP4 or IP6 address. IP4 are in decimal format.

Comment: You can check whether provided IP is IP4 or IP6 before trying with inet_pton. I guess that will make it faster. There are many ways to achieve it. One simple solution is to use regular expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is parse characters from the current line until you hit either a non-decimal digit (since IPv6 uses hex, while IPv4 generally doesn't if we can assume dotted-decimal) or a colon.

If you hit a dot instead, you know the line is an IPv4 address, else it's IPv6.

That extra parsing of up to four bytes should be *really* fast.

Here's an attempt at implementing this classification function:

```
int get_af(const char *address)
{
  while(isdigit((unsigned int) *address))
    ++address;
  if(*address == '.')
    return AF_INET;
  if(*address == ':' || isxdigit((unsigned int) *address))
    return AF_INET6;
  return -1;
}
```

The above assumes that neither `AF_INET` nor `AF_INET6` is -1, since that is used for error-reporting. This might need tweaking.